# What is the purpose of method First in a TAdoQuery in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Could you please explain to me the purpose of  the following lines, especially for the First method ?

```
TestQ.First;
  while not TestQ.Eof do
```

Comment: Nitpicking: `First` isn't a keyword. It's a method.

Comment: By the way, did you read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.First) and [1](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_the_First_and_Last_Methods)? Of course the documentation often doesn't explain everything and is sometimes unclear or incomplete, but it's still good to mention the docs (like "I have read the docs, but still don't quite understand why ... ") in the Q if for no other reason than to prevent users from answering your Q by simply pointing to the docs you already have read!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I was trying to understand the First method through the Data.Win.ADODB  file but it didn't seem really helpful

Comment: TDataSet and its descendants like TAdoAquery and TAdoTable have a standard set of navigation methods including First, Last, Next and Prior which move the dataset's "cursor".  First simply moves the cursor to the first record in the dataset, according to the dataset's current order.

Answer (score 3):

TDataSet and its descendants like TAdoAquery and TAdoTable have a standard set of navigation methods including First, Last, Next, Prior and MoveBy which move the dataset's "cursor" in the manner the method name describes.

Unless the dataset is empty, the dataset's cursor always points to exactly one record in the dataset, known as the "active" record, which is the one on which data-reading and data-writing operations take place.  When db-aware components are used to display fields from the dataset, it is the values of the fields of the active record which are displayed. (In a TDBGrid, the current record is highlighted).

`First` simply moves the cursor to the first record in the dataset, according to the dataset's current order and taking into account any active filter on the dataset.

Btw, the standard behaviour when opening a non-empty TDataSet places the cursor on the first record in it, so has the same effect at calling `First`.  Generally, `First` is called before traversing a dataset so that the traversal starts at a known position.

Comment: Does that answer your q?  If not, what else were you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

the idea , iterate a query  with the  following code

```
AnyQuery.first;
while (not AnyQuery.EOF) do
   begin 
   ///   enter your query code here
   ....
   ...
   .
   ///   Move to the next query record 
   AnyQuery.Next ;    
   end;
```